# How to use ColorDialog to place text in Textbox in C# / Excel Interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel-interop

How do you use the colorDialog to place the text version of a color into a textbox?  I have a textbox and I fir the colorDialog upon clicking a button next to it.  The tsring of the color goes into the text box, but the final result is of the form 'Color [Green]'  and not simply 'Green'.  Is there a better way to do this.  My current code is as follows:

```
public partial class ColorTie : Form
{
    public ColorTie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ColorTie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = colorDialog1.Color.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe the property you're looking for is [`Color.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.name%28VS.90%29.aspx).

If your user selects red from your dialog, `colorDialog1.Color.Name` will return the string "Red".  Beware though, because the user might select a color that doesn't have a Color.Name property value. To guard against this, you can check the [`Color.IsNamedColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.isnamedcolor%28VS.90%29.aspx); if it's true you can use `Color.Name` like I described (otherwise you get back the RGB value).

Something like this:

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    if (colorDialog1.Color.IsNamedColor) {
        Console.WriteLine("Named color: {0}", colorDialog1.Color.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
textBox1.Text = colorDialog1.Color.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color in PictureBox, this is the best way for visualize and memorize your color choise:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
    if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cd.Color.ToString());
        pictureBox1.BackColor = cd.Color;
    }

}
```